# Optimization levels in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, optimization

I have googled this question to clear some basic concepts but didn't find a suitable answer for this.

How many optimization levels are available for code generation in Xcode build setting for the Swift compiler and Apple LLVM (Objective-C)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Swift provides four different optimization levels:

**`-Onone:`**

> This is meant for normal development. It performs minimal
>   optimizations and preserves all debug info.

**`-O:`**

> This is meant for most production code. The compiler performs
>   aggressive optimizations that can drastically change the type and
>   amount of emitted code. Debug information will be emitted but will be
>   lossy.

**`-Ounchecked:`**

> This is a special optimization mode meant for specific libraries or
>   applications where one is willing to trade safety for performance. The
>   compiler will remove all overflow checks as well as some implicit type
>   checks. This is not intended to be used in general since it may result
>   in undetected memory safety issues and integer overflows. Only use
>   this if you have carefully reviewed that your code is safe with
>   respect to integer overflow and type casts.

**`-Osize:`**

> This is a special optimization mode where the compiler prioritizes
>   code size over performance.

You can ready more about these here: [OptimizationTips](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OptimizationTips.rst?source=post_page---------------------------#enabling-optimizations)

Comment: Could you explain the meaning behind all the acronyms? "Onone" is especially cryptic.

Comment: @PeterSchorn -O is prefix for Optimization, so they are `none`, `Optimized`, `unchecked` and `size`.

Comment: does setting the the flag to NONE, could affect the overall performance of the app once in the Appstore ?

Comment: None is usually brutally slower. You compile debug and release with different settings.

Comment: The article doesn't mention `-Ounchecked` level. Has it been removed?

Answer (score 3):

**Optimization Level (GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL) and Optimization Level(SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL)**

[[Xcode build process]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216120/4770877)

**Objective-C GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL**

It is a part of IR Generation and Optimization `AST -> LLVM IR`

- `None [-O0]`(by default for debug) - not optimized code for debug
- `Fast [-O, O1]` - between -O0 and -O2 simple optimizations with minimum compile time
- `Faster [-O2]` - better optimizations and higher compile time
- `Fastest [-O3]` - [-O2] + optimizations without compile time or code footprint limits. the best optimizations and highest compile time
- `Fastest, Smallest [-Os]`(by default for release) - [-O2] + optimizations for reduce code size
- `Fastest, Aggressive optimization [-Ofast]` - [-O3] + aggressive optimizations which can violate strict language compliance
- `Smallest, Aggressive Size Optimizations [-Oz]` - [-Os] + optimizations for redusing code footprint

**Swift SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL**

It is a part of IR Generation and Optimization[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216120/4770877)

- `-Onone`(by default for app debug) - minimal optimizations(debug) - build time up, performance down
- `-O` - maximum optimizations(by default for app release) - build time down, performance up

  - `-O -whole-module-optimization` - compiler look at **all** the source files in a module(except single source file at time). For example execution a function from not the same **file**(in module scope) will be faster
- `-Osize` - size over perfomance

//Additional

- `-Ounchecked` - performance over safety

**SWIFT_DISABLE_SAFETY_CHECKS**

`Disable Safety Checks(SWIFT_DISABLE_SAFETY_CHECKS)` (by default is `false`) - Disable runtime safety checks when optimizing is enabled(`SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL` == `-O`, `-Osize`) (`-Ounchecked`) and it is not taken into account with `-Onone`

[[-O vs -O -whole-module-optimization]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74836011/4770877)