# wait() and notify() JMM semantics

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, java-memory-model, happens-before

I have a very particular question I couldn't find an answer to.

As we know, on entrance in `synchronized` blocks a thread performs a re-read of all the shared (non-local) variables in it's scope. Example for certain underlying architectures: if thread A updates the object's state in RAM thread B entering a synchronized block will see the changes.
Similar thing happens on exit from `synchronized` block: the thread flushes everything in it's scope to the RAM so it can be seen by other threads.
Those are basic JVM visibility guarantees and the happens-before rules are present to enforce it.

However, semantically it is not very clear if the code using `wait()` or `notify()` also does all of this: after all it does not explicily enter or leave the `synchronized` block.

The questions are these:

1. Does the JVM ensure the visibility of changes to other threads on `wait()` entrance?
2. Does the JVM ensure the visibility of changes made in other threads on `wait()` leave?
3. Does the thread ensure the visibility of changes to other threads on  `notify()`?

Comment: When a thread enters/leaves the wait method it does explicitly have to release/reacquire the lock.

Comment: Not sure why the question has been closed as "too broad". While it seemingly contains 3 sub-questions, they are very close to themselves. Voted for reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As we know, on entrance in synchronized blocks a thread performs a re-read of all the variables in it's scope; that is, if thread A updates the object's state in RAM thread B entering a synchronized block will see the changes.

The first part of that is incorrect.  All variables are not reread.  Local variables definite won't be.  They don't *need* to be reread because they are never visible to another thread.

The correct statement is the compiler will ensure that *shared* variables that were written by thread A *before* exiting the block will be visible to thread B *after* it has entered the block.  Provided that A and B are synchronizing on the same mutex object, and provided that A (or some other thread) did not overwrite them in the meantime.

There are no explicit memory semantics associated with a `notify` or `notifyAll`.  However, a `wait` will cause the mutex to be released and (typically) re-acquired.  The release and re-acquisition have associated *happens-before* relations with with some other thread.

---

> Could you, please, elaborate on exact semantics associated with releasing and acquiring a lock? Are they one and same with entering the synchronized block?

Lets assume we have just two threads, A and B, and a single mutex L.  Lets assume that we start with neither thread holding the mutex.

Also remember that `wait` and `notify` can only be called by a thread that holds a lock

1. Thread A acquires L.
2. Thread A calls `L.wait()`.

   - Thread A is placed on the wait queue for L, and L is released.
3. Thread B acquires L.
4. Thread B calls `L.notify()`

   - Thread A is moved on the queue of threads waiting to acquire L.
5. Thread B releases L.
6. Thread A re-acquires the lock, and the `L.wait()` call returns.

The *happens-before* edges that matter here are between 2 and 3, and then between 5 and 6.

If there are multiple threads involved, you can analyze the behavior by chaining the *happens-before* relations.  But there is only a direct HB between the thread that releases the mutex and the next thread to acquire it ... by any means.

---

So, the answers to your questions are:

1) & 2) Yes, assuming that the other thread is using `synchronized` correctly.
3) No.  The visibility point is when the mutex is released by the thread that called `notify()`.

---

Note that memory barriers, flushes and so on are implementation details.  In fact, a compiler is free to implement the semantics of *happens-before* any way that it wants to.  Including (hypothetically) optimizing away memory flushes if they are not necessary.

It is best (IMO) to ignore these implementation details and *only* think about the *happens-before* relationships.

For more information on *happens-before*, read:

- [How to understand happens-before consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970428/how-to-understand-happens-before-consistent)
- The Memory Model chapter of "Java concurrency in action" by Brian Goetz et al
- The JVM spec Chapter 17.4

Comment: Yes, that is what I implied -- obviously local variables are exempt from JMM semantics as they are, well, local. Sorry if this was not clear, I'll update my question.
Could you, please, elaborate on exact semantics associated with releasing and acquiring a lock? Are they one and same with enteryng the `synchronized` block?

Comment: I rephrased the question to exclude implementation semantics from it, as it was not intended to be the point of the question.

Comment: Thanks for all of the updates.
Could you please, for the last one, explicitly state whether happens-before edge you are talking about here guarantees visibility and not just order-of-execution? I am new to Java world and I have not much intuition on implications yet. Also, this answer can be looked up by people in future.

Comment: It guarantees visibility ... and hence *restricts* out-of-order execution across the HB.  Note that there are other Q&A's that explain what *happens-before* actually means.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make that as clear as possible for archival purpose.