# Writing to a volatile field and reading another volatile field: Is the happens-before-rule valid?

Tags: java, visibility, volatile, java-memory-model, happens-before

Question: Is this statement true: „A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that **or another volatile** field.“

On [How to understand happens-before consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970428/how-to-understand-happens-before-consistent) I found the following statements:

Happens-before: „Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.“

Volatile: „A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that field.“

Visibility: „When Thread A changes/writes a volatile variable it also pushes all previous changes into RAM - Main Memory as a result all not volatile variable will be up to date and visible for another threads“.

In the following program, according to the java memory model, it is **not guaranteed** that the output "thread end" will appear on the console:

```
public class VolatileQuestion {

static boolean finish = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (!finish);
        System.out.println("thread end");
    }).start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    finish = true;
    System.out.println("main end");
}
}
```

Declaring field „finish" as volatile it **is guaranteed** that the output "thread end" will appear on the console:

```
public class VolatileQuestion {

static volatile boolean finish = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (!finish);
        System.out.println("thread end");
    }).start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    finish = true;
    System.out.println("main end");
}
}
```

In the third program, I don't declare field finish as volatile, but I introduce another field declared as volatile, which the main thread writes and the other thread reads. Therefore, according to the java memory model, the output of "thread end" **is guaranteed**:

```
public class VolatileQuestion {

static boolean finish = false;
static volatile boolean flush = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (!finish) {
            boolean dummy = flush;
        }
        System.out.println("thread end");
    }).start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    finish = true;
    flush = true;
    System.out.println("main end");
}
}
```

And now my question: What happens if I write a volatile field in the main thread and read another volatile field in the other thread: Is the output of "thread end" guaranteed in that case too?

```
public class VolatileQuestion {

static boolean finish = false;
static volatile boolean flush = false;
static volatile boolean refresh = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (!finish) {
            boolean dummy = refresh;
        }
        System.out.println("thread end");
    }).start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    finish = true;
    flush = true;
    System.out.println("main end");
}
}
```

Comment: The last snippet does not use refresh in any meaningful way. Nothing in the code depends on its value. It behaves exactly as the sniper before it.

Comment: The 4th version is equivalent to the 2nd one.  The HB relation involving `finish` is the same.  (The `flush` variable doesn't alter the HB relation for `finish`.  It is just redundant.)   And you can make a similar argument to say that the 4th version is equivalent to the 3rd version.

Comment: clearification: the reason for the instruction "boolean dummy = refresh;" is solely to refresh the cache of the thread. And my question is "Is it really refreshed"? If i replace the statement with "boolean dummy = flush;" the refresh is guaranteed!

Comment: Stephen: In the 3rd and 4th version finish ist not declared as volatile!

Comment: [4.5. Wishful Thinking: Unobserved Volatiles Have Memory Effects](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#wishful-unobserved-volatiles) • [4.6. Wishful Thinking: Mismatched Ops Are Okay](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#wishful-mismatched)

Comment: If a volatile read sees a particular volatile write then there is a happens-before relation between that write and that read.

This makes it clear that it implies the same variable and this also makes clear that there is only a happens-before relation if that read sees that  write. This also removes 'time' from the definition. Time can be very confusing with the JMM.

Comment: A correctly synchronized program in Java can only have sequential consistent executions. The real-time order doesn't need to be respected for sequential consistency. And this often leads to very hard-to-understand wording that gives the impression that the real-time order needs to be respected (especially when you see things like subsequent).

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if I write a volatile field in the main thread and read another volatile field in the other thread

There are no guarantees in this case. Writing to a volatile field doesn't guarantee anything about any other variables. You get guarantees only by reading the same variable from a different thread.

In the fourth version of the code, the only thing tying the two threads together is `finish`, which is non-volatile and provides no guarantees.