# Are Lists<T> thread safe to add/write to?

Tags: java, multithreading, list, collections

I want to add information to a List and that information is gathered from multiple threads. The threads do not need to pull data from the list. Is it safe to have a regular ArrayList or LinkedList? Or what other ways can I do this?

Comment: The regular collections are not inherently thread safe. Simplest way is to lock around access to a list<T>

Comment: You can use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203913/2928853

Comment: Documentation: [ArraList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html): "**Note that this implementation is not synchronized.**  If multiple threads access an `ArrayList`/a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally...."

Comment: Even for thread safe lists, adding concurrently implies an unpredictable order, which raises the question why the code is using a `List`…

Answer (score 4):

Regular collections are not thread safe, but there are ways to circunvent that:

You can use [CopyOnWriteArrayLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), but they are very expensive to write, you can also create a [Syncronized Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection(java.util.Collection)), which are not so expensive to write, and you can also work with [Queues](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html), it will depend on what you want to achieve.

Comment: "Collections are not thread safe" - Collections in [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) **are** thread-safe.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045648/which-java-collections-are-synchronizedthread-safe-which-are-not